# Merge two arrays by key and append value form one array to other

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have two arrays. Each array have key "test1" and "test2" for example:

```
$array = [
   "test1" => [
        'value' => 1, 
        "date"=> '2019-01-01'
    ], 
    "test2" => [
        'value' => 2, 
        "date"=> '2019-01-01'
    ]
];
$array2 = [
    "test1" => [
        'value' => 3, 
        "date"=> '2018-01-01'
    ], 
    "test2" => [
        'value' => 4, 
        "date"=> '2018-01-01'
    ]
];
```

All I need is merge these arrays in way let me output like this:

```
$finalArray = [
    "test1" => [
        [
            'value' => 1, 
            "date"=> '2019-01-01'
        ], 
        [
            'value' => 3, 
            "date"=> '2018-01-01'
        ]
    ],
    "test2" => [
        [
            'value' => 2, 
            "date"=> '2019-01-01'
        ],
        [
            'value' => 4, 
            "date"=> '2018-01-01'
        ]
    ]
];
```

It find key from first array and add to this key value from other array on the same key.

Array merge not works for me because it overwrite my keys. Can I do this without foreach on both tables and checking key? Is maybe one method which can do this?

Comment: Why people are so much against about using `foreach()`? It's good actually.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `array_map` ([documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)):

```
$res = array_map(null, $array1, $array2);
```

Notice for the `null` passed as callback:

> NULL can be passed as a value to callback to perform a zip operation on multiple arrays

Live example [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/CYDAB).

Notice this will remove the original keys. You can return them by `array_combine` and `array_keys` as:

```
$res = array_map(null, $array1, $array2);
$res = array_combine(array_keys($array1), $res);
```

Comment: thanks :) but what if one array have more elements than other? Then i have error: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements

Comment: If that the case you should do simple `foreach` as said in the comment above. This way is for speed up specific cases